# Sampling from the wrapped normal distribution and obtaining the density simultaneously

Tags: c++, random, c++17, distribution, normal-distribution

Say `double x, sigma` are given and we want to sample `y` from the [wrapped normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapped_normal_distribution) on `[0, 1)` with mean `x` and standard deviation `sigma`.

Can we, in a clever way, obtain the sample `y` simultaneously with the value `q(y)` of the density `q` at `y`?

Sampling `y` is, for sure, simple:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 g{ rd() };
std::normal_distribution<> d;

double y = x + sigma * d(g);
y -= std::floor(y);
```

But now I'd need to compute `q(y)` separately. Maybe we can obtain `q(y)` as a byproduct using inverse transform sampling instead.

*Remark*: If `phi` denotes the density of the normal distribution with mean `0` and standard deviation `sigma` and `psi(x)` denotes the sum of `phi(k + x)` over all integers `k`, then the wrapped normal distribution on `[0, 1)` with mean `x` and standard deviation `sigma` has the density `q(y) := psi(y - x)`.

Comment: How would evaluating them “together” be superior to just evaluating (a suitable truncation of) the sum afterwards?  Are you concerned about a very large `sigma` or something?

Comment: That might be relevant https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268443292_Efficient_Evaluation_of_the_Probability_Density_Function_of_a_Wrapped_Normal_Distribution